# What are exceptions?

Tags: c#, c++, language-agnostic, exception

We talk about exception handling everyday. We all konw that it is something that is created when execution meet some unexpected situation.

Here come several questions:

- What is an exception? What's its most low-level in-memory composition? In .NET, I can think of it as some object instance of some exception *type*. In the native world, what is it made of? Some data sturcures?
- Who create the exception if the exception is not thrown explicitly by the programmer as the following code shows? Is it part of the support that certain language runtime provides?

  SomeException e = new SomeException();
  throw e;
- What is the exception working paradigm? Is it true that when some error happens, an instnace of the corresponding *data structure/type* is created by the language runtime to represent the details of the error?
- How could we know all the possible unexpected situations at runtime and thus create enough exception *data structures/types* to represent them?

Thanks for your replies.

Comment: Strange. You even have "wikipedia" as part of your name. The answers are not there? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exception_handling Or are you researching this topic to extend the article?

Comment: Is this question really bound to C++ and C#? Does it not apply to other languages as well?

Comment: sorry, but too many tags is not allowed.

Comment: -1 for trying to raise a flame war :-). What is you point indeed? Are you preparing interview questions, or are you studying for an interview/test? Reviewing you other questions I got an impression, that you are working for sth. like http://brainbench.com/, right? :-)

Comment: Also take a look [here](http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/a-look-at-exceptions-in-.net-applications/)

Answer (score 14):

The answers to your questions depend a lot on what language we're talking about.

***C doesn't have exceptions*** at all, although there are proprietary language extensions.
***C++*** has a way to "throw" an ***arbitrary object*** at any point in your code and "catch" it somewhere higher up the call stack.
***C#*** has a way to "throw" ***objects derived from `System.Exception`*** and also "catch" those from higher up the stack. Additionally, I think the .NET runtime reports some issues per throwing an exception itself.

> - What is an exception? What's its most low-level in-memory composition? In .NET, I can think of it as some object instance of some exception type. In the native world, what is it made of? Some data sturcures?

In C++, it's simply an arbitrary object, that was created like other objects in code:

```
throw 42;                     // throws an int object
throw "blah";                 // throws a char[5] object
throw std::string("arg!");    // throws a std::string object
throw my_type(42);            // throws a my_type object
throw std::exception("doh!"); // throws a std::exception object
```

The matching of thrown exceptions to `catch` phrases is pretty similar to the matching of overloaded functions. (A big difference is that catch phrases are *ordered*. That is, the first to match at all will "win" and catch the object. Overloaded functions, however, must always provide an unambiguously best match.)

> - Who create the exception if the exception is not thrown explicitly by the programmer as the following code shows? Is it part of the support that certain language runtime provides?

In C++, exceptions can almost only be thrown from code. It could be your own code, someone else's code, some library's code, or the standard library's code. But there will usually have to be a `throw` statement somewhere. There are a few exceptions (no pun intended) to this, like `std::bad_alloc` thrown by `new` (which is likely thrown from a `throw` statement in code, but I think doesn't have to) and `std::bad_cast`, thrown from `dynamic_cast<>`. (Also, the next standard, C++1x, expected next year, allows exceptions to somehow cross thread borders, which probably requires standard library implementors to find a way to store an exception in one thread and rethrow it from another. But I'm pretty hazy on this.)

> ```
>     SomeException e = new SomeException(); throw e;
> ```

In C++ you *can*, but you rarely ever would want to, throw *pointers*. You either do

```
SomeException e; throw e;
```

or

```
throw SomeException();
```

> - What is the exception working paradigm? Is it true that when some error happens, an instnace of the corresponding data structure/type is created by the language runtime to represent the details of the error?

There area few places where the C++ standard library throws exceptions, but other than that I can only think of the two features mentioned above (plus the one in C++1x) where the runtime throws exceptions "itself".

> - How could we know all the possible unexpected situations at runtime and thus create enough exception data structures/types to represent them?

It's common to only throw objects of classes derived from `std::exception` in C++, although I have come across code that used their own exception class hierarchy which wasn't rooted in `std::exception`. The problem with the exception hierarchy in the standard library is that its classes derives non-virtually from each other, which makes it impossible to have your own exception hierarchy shadowing the one from the standard library using multiple inheritance. (Like having your own `OutOfRange` exception type that inherits from `std::out_of_range` and from your exception base class `MyException`, which inherits from `std::exception`.)

The C++ way to deal with exceptions is mainly based on the following principles:

- Write your code in ways that makes it immune to exceptions thrown at any point. Use [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) and other techniques to achieve that.
- Catch exceptions only at places where you can do something about them.
- Throw exceptions only in exceptionally circumstances. Do not use them for control flow. (C++ exceptions were designed with the goal for vendors to be able to implement them so that the overhead is minimized in the non-exceptional case, at the cost of the exceptional case.)

Comment: I suppose you're far above explaining what's wrong with this? Or why have you down-voted?

Answer (score 1):

At its root an exception is a special situation with a predefined handling mechanism. All the rest is up to the implementation.

The *type* is there because it's convenient to have an object storing extra data on the kind of the special situation. That said an exception could be a controlled switch that would for example just restart a machine each time the hardware can't perform the operation.

Answer (score 1):

Exceptions are effectively a manner of error handling where it interrupts the flow such that it can no longer continue.

There are two sides to the exception, the thrower and the catcher. The thrower is responsible for detecting that the error has occurred, create an exception class to contain the error information and "throw" it. Pretty much it is like putting it inside a ball and throwing the ball - at this point its job is done and it is up to the "catcher" now.

The catcher is the error-handling mechanism that knows how to handle the error. You may find a catcher only knows how to handle certain types of error. This is handled by the type hierarchy although in my opinion it would be better if this were not done with run-time type information because of the overhead this can cause.

Use of exceptions in normal flow is generally not desirable, eg when you read a file until the end - end-of-file is not an error but an excepted occurrence and should be handled with normal flow not with exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

Exceptions are a way of handing error situations. The alternative are return values, and lots of ifs and switch/cases.

It is true that the exception acts like a hidden goto, but the final code is easier to maintain then it's alternative.

Handling exceptions is fairly easy. All exceptions that are thrown in the code should have a common base class, which logs the error. All exceptions should carry enough information what exactly happened.

It is also true that the exceptions should not be misused in a way that they should be thrown for every little thing. If possible, error should be handled locally. If not, throw an exception which will be caught at the level where the exception can be dealt with.

And the final note : c++ without exceptions is not c++, it is a c with classes

Comment: Alas, Google wouldn't agree with your last comment, judging from their style guide http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.xml?showone=Exceptions#Exceptions

Comment: @beldaz I know, but they are probably having their own reasons for making such coding rules.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, my answer is for C++ only. C does not have exceptions and I am not familiar enough with C# to make statements that include that language as well.

An exception object is just that, an object. It can be an object of some class type, but it can just as easily be an integer. It can be compared somewhat with the return value from a function. The big difference is that storing an exception on the stack is problematic due to the control-flow involved in exception handling.

In C++, all exceptions are always the result of a `throw` statement. With Microsoft SEH, it is the language-runtime that creates the SEH exceptions. So, there is always some code that creates the exception object.

In C++, the language runtime does not have to know about all possible application-level exceptions that can be thrown. It just has to provide a mechanism that the `catch`-handler can access (a copy of) the exception object being thrown. How this is achieved is up to the compiler writers.

Answer (score 0):

When the code want to do a operation  in computer who can't possible that the certain code thrown an exception.

because we know that if it comes in client system then he can create problem so he use exceptionhandeling to handle the exception.

here is a useful series

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Search/en-IN?query=exception+handling&ac=8

Answer (score 0):

Traditional error handling methodologies have serious problems:

- Returning an error code from the method requires **each and every** call to be wrapped into `if` that checks for the error. This alone would nearly double the codebase and if you forget to do it just once, your program is no longer robust.
- Global error code (a-la `errno` in C) is not thread-safe.
- Any kind of error code is just a number. It is hard to convey more sophisticated details about the actual error.
- Even if you use "exception structures", it is **hard to compose** them - different layers of code might use different structures.
- Etc...

Exceptions allow you to:

- Convey rich information about the error, since you are throwing real objects and not just error codes. The type of the object does not have to be predetermined and can "match" the error at the run-time (in fact, one of the major motivations for RTTI in C++ was to determine the run-type type of the thrown exception).
- **Decouple** error detection from error handling. Error detection is done in a piece of code that has most knowledge about the error (at the bottom of the call hierarchy), while error handling can be done in the much higher layer of code, presumably the one that knows something about UI.
- The code layers **in between** don't have to know about any of this (but they do need to be written in the "exception safe" way).

---

> What is an exception?

An object.

> Who create the exception...?

In C++, object is **copied** before being thrown, since compiler needs to guarantee the lifetime of the exception during stack unwinding, for as long as there is any `catch` block that can catch it.

In C#, with its garbage collector, we can retain original object even during stack unwinding.

> What is the exception working paradigm?

Exceptions model exceptional events. If something is frequent, then it is *probably* not an exception.

Each kind of error can be represented by an instance of a different class if appropriate. Or you could represent every error with the same class. Or anything in between. There are no hard-and-fast rules.

> How could we know all the possible unexpected situations at runtime and thus create enough exception data structures/types to represent them?

You know how *your* code can fail, so you can design **your exceptions** appropriately. In a code that other people wrote, assume it can throw anything anytime, unless proven otherwise.

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you know if any languages have a means by which exceptions can decouple (1) what problem triggered them; (2) what needs to happen as a result; and (3) how far things need to unwind before code can continue normally?  Whole those factors are related, they are also distinct, especially in situations where multiple problems may exist.  For example, an operation to import and merge an XML document into a data structure may fail in such a way as to leave the data structure in its original state, partially updated but intact, or totally corrupted....

Comment: ...and the source of the XML data (from the point of view of the outside code) may be disturbed or not, independent of whether the data structure was corrupted.  What should ideally happen, IMHO, would be that any "catch" code for either data-source problems or data-destination problems should run if the condition exists, but if both conditions exist, the exception should be rethrown after the handler for the first condition exists.  Unfortunately, I don't know any remotely-normal pattern for handling such things.

Comment: @supercat Ummm... all of them? ;) Exception are designed for exactly this kind of decoupling. As for XML parsing example, it is the responsibility of the code that **throws** to leave the data structure in the consistent state (whatever this may mean in that particular case). This would have to be done no matter how you report the error - through an error code or exception or whatever...

Comment: @supercat Exceptions force a certain change in paradigm - even the code that has nothing to do with exceptions must assume that each and every sub-method it calls could throw, unless proven otherwise (which is rare). However, similar thing would have to be done with the traditional error handling as well. The fact that it often isn't does not mean traditional error handling is easier, it simply means it is easier to **ignore**, leading to the program that is not handling all the errors it should.

Comment: @supercat At the end of the day, programs using exceptions tend to be **both** cleaner and more robust than programs using traditional error handling.

Comment: The code from which which the exception is thrown should certainly try to leave things in a consistent state; that doesn't mean that such efforts will always succeed.  For example, a method which is supposed to copy data from one stream to another may, through no fault of its own, end up with either or both streams in an inconsistent or unusable state if one stream experiences unexpected difficulty and an attempt to clean up the other stream's state fails.  The code should unwind to a point that doesn't require either stream to be valid, but I don't know any way for normal pattern to do that.

Comment: @supercat That's what I mean by "exception safe" code. You should always assume any line of code could throw and structure your code so it doesn't matter. Idioms such as [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAII) in C++ or `IDisposable` in C# are instrumental for achieving that goal. In your example, if either of the streams fail, `RAII` guard or `using` would automatically "clean up" the other one as well.

Comment: @supercat OTOH, if the **cleanup itself** fails, then your program probably can't handle that kind of error at all, so there is very little to do other than abort the program (that's why exceptions in C++ destructors are [so problematic](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/exceptions.html#faq-17.9)). This is rarely a practical concern though.

Comment: With things like streams, it's entirely possible that the cleanup itself could fail (e.g. because the program was copying a file from one directory to another on a memory stick, and the stick got unplugged).  The user should be informed that the source file couldn't be read, and that the state of the destination file is unknown, but those problems shouldn't cause the program to die and make the user lose any documents that were open.  Is that scenario really unrealistic?

Comment: @supercat This scenario does not imply that stream cannot be "cleaned up". What you'll typically get is an exception when attempting to perform the next operation on that stream, and **after** that the clean-up code will release the file handle to the OS or whatever. On the other hand, if the stream library you are using really cannot recover after that, then yes, program should die. That's less dangerous than attempting to continue while data structures are garbled up, and the risking corruption of the data that is already in persistent storage (if you have another stream, for example).

Comment: On many file systems, file-write operations may return before data is actually written, but an OS-level "file close" operation will flush buffers and return an error if the write was unsuccessful.  If an error occurs during that write operation it should not be stifled, but nor should it terminate the application (especially since the fact that it failed may create a need for the user to save his documents somewhere else).  Further, I would suggest that if one wants to avoid escalating corruption, the proper approach is to have data structures invalidate themselves while unwinding the stack.

Comment: @supercat Is it worse to lose the error or terminate the application? C++ designers thought the former is worse and C# designers the latter. So if you throw from C++ destructor while the stack is unwinding, you terminate. If you throw from C# `Dispose` while the stack is unwinding, you "overwrite" the previous exception. If you want to avoid both, don't wait for destructor/Dispose, close the stream and handle any exceptions explicitly. I don't see why this would be any worse than what you'd have to do with "traditional" error handling.

Comment: My original question was whether you knew of any languages or frameworks which allowed one to both keep the new exception and the old.  Conceptually, it shouldn't be hard to design a system in which code in a "catch" block would run if it matched any pending exceptions, but stack unwinding would continue after a catch block if any exceptions were still unresolved.  I was curious whether you know of any.

Comment: @supercat OK, I think only now I actually understand your original question ;) And no, I'm afraid I don't know any such language/framework. Interesting idea though!

Comment: Too bad, since I think such a thing could avoid the Scylla/Charybdis of "crash on anything unexpected" and "use Pokemon exception handlers".  The most important question when deciding whether an exception should propagate is whether anything is in a *state* which the code above isn't going to be expecting; I'd really like to see an exception-handling mechanism that puts that question first and foremost.